# Keep getting segmentation fault even on changing the code

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have been working on a hashtable. I keep getting a segmentation fault. I have been trying to debug it, but it always points to `addOrder` having segmentation fault.

Where am i going wrong? Also what other ways could I implement my code to check for any corner cases?

```
struct order 
{
    int id;
    char side;
    int quantity;
    double price;
};

struct onode 
{
    struct order* data;
    struct onode* next;
    struct onode* prev;
};

/*
 * Create a new instance of struct hashStorage and return it. It sets the size of the
 * table to be of length "size" which will be the number of the entries in the hash. It takes also an
 * argument to specify the format of the order printed to an output stream. If myHash parameter
 * is NULL then this means that the hash should be a linked list. When myHash is NULL the size
 * parameter should be ignored.
 */

struct hashStorage* createHash(int size, int (*myHash)(int),void(*printOrder)(struct order *, FILE *))
{
    struct hashStorage* hashList = (struct hashStorage*) malloc(sizeof(struct hashStorage));

    if(myHash == NULL)
    {
        hashList->size = 1;
        hashList->table = (struct onode**) calloc(1, sizeof(struct onode*));
    }

    if(myHash != NULL)
    {
        hashList->table = (struct onode**) calloc(size, sizeof(struct onode*));
        hashList->size = size;
    }
    hashList->funcHash = myHash;
    hashList->printItem = printOrder;        
    return hashList;
}

/*
 * Add an order to the hash structure. Remember that you should copy the data before
 * adding it to the hash as data can be modified (hint: look at newNode in list).  
 * It returns the new onode.              
 */
struct onode* addOrder(struct hashStorage* hash, struct order* data)
{
    int addIndex; 
    struct onode* dataList = newNode(data);
    addIndex = hash -> funcHash(getOrderId(data));
    pushNode(&(hash->table[addIndex]), dataList);
    return dataList;                            
}
```

Comment: do you know what specific line causes the segmentation fault?

Comment: fyi you missing a / in first comment

Comment: no it just says addOrder argv have garbage value

Comment: @NullPonyPointer thats a typo i am pretty sure that cannot cause a segmentation fault. that will be a compiler error.

Comment: also, what code calls addOrder?

Comment: we have a different file and we use input using command line

Comment: well, it's hard to figure out what is the problem with addOrder() if the input is not known. My first guess is that some pointer is null or not valid (memory not allocated perhaps?)

Comment: Have you compiled with -g and run it through gdb?

Comment: @Quirliom yes, that is how i came to know where the error is.

Comment: @Maddy, If you stepped through this in gdb, you would know the values of `hash`, `data`, `addIndex` and `dataList` inside `addOrder()`. Also, you would know exactly which line caused the segfault. Did you analyse those values to see if you're accessing invalid memory or some such?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to take a look at GHashTable code from [glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/) library, it has a quite well commented code, which you will be able to understand.

Hope it helps !